# Send the contents from unmodified print statement by e-mail in python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have a script that runs `main()` and at the end I want to send the contents it has by e-mail. I don't want to write new files nor anything. Just have the original script be unmodified and at the end just send the contents of what it printed. Ideal code:

```
main()
send_mail()
```

I tried this:

```
def main():
  print('HELLOWORLD')

def send_email(subject='subject', message='', destination='me@gmail.com', password_path=None):
    from socket import gethostname
    from email.message import EmailMessage
    import smtplib
    import json
    import sys

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtplib.stdout = sys.stdout # <<<<<-------- why doesn't it work?
    server.starttls()
    with open(password_path) as f:
        config = json.load(f)
        server.login('me@gmail.com', config['password'])

        # craft message
        msg = EmailMessage()

        #msg.set_content(message)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = 'me@gmail.com'
        msg['To'] = destination
        # send msg
        server.send_message(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    send_mail()
```

but it doesn't work.

I don't want to write other files or change the original python print statements. How to do this?

---

I tried this:

```
def get_stdout():
    import sys

    print('a')
    print('b')
    print('c')

    repr(sys.stdout)

    contents = ""
    #with open('some_file.txt') as f:
    #with open(sys.stdout) as f:
    for line in sys.stdout.readlines():
        contents += line
    print(contents)
```

but it does not let me read `sys.stdout` because it says its not readable. How can I open it in readable or change it to readable in the first place?

---

I checked all of the following links but none helped:

- [How to send output from a python script to an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247653/how-to-send-output-from-a-python-script-to-an-email-address)
- https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-send-an-output-from-a-Python-script-to-an-email-address
- https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/165835-email-module-redirecting-stdout
- [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)
- [How to handle both `with open(...)` and `sys.stdout` nicely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602878/how-to-handle-both-with-open-and-sys-stdout-nicely)
- [Capture stdout from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

To send e-mails I am using:

```
def send_email(subject, message, destination, password_path=None):
    from socket import gethostname
    from email.message import EmailMessage
    import smtplib
    import json

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    with open(password_path) as f:
        config = json.load(f)
        server.login('me123@gmail.com', config['password'])
        # craft message
        msg = EmailMessage()

        message = f'{message}\nSend from Hostname: {gethostname()}'
        msg.set_content(message)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = 'me123@gmail.com'
        msg['To'] = destination
        # send msg
        server.send_message(msg)
```

note I have my password in a json file using an app password as suggested by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996409/3167448.

using this to collect the contents from stdout by writing it to a custom stdout file using the builtin function print:

```
import sys 
from pathlib import Path
def my_print(*args, filepath='~/my_stdout.txt'):
    filepath = Path(filepath).expanduser()
    # do normal print
    __builtins__['print'](*args, file=sys.__stdout__) #prints to terminal
    # open my stdout file in update mode
    with open(filepath, "a+") as f:
        # save the content we are trying to print
        __builtins__['print'](*args, file=f) #saves in a file

def collect_content_from_file(filepath):
    filepath = Path(filepath).expanduser()
    contents = ''
    with open(filepath,'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            contents = contents + line
    return contents
```

Note the `a+` to be able to create the file if it already does NOT exist.

Note that if you want to delete the old contents of your custom `my_stdout.txt` you need to delete the file and check if it exists:

```
    # remove my stdout if it exists
    os.remove(Path('~/my_stdout.txt').expanduser()) if os.path.isfile(Path('~/my_stdout.txt').expanduser()) else None
```

The credits for the print code are from the answer here: [How does one make an already opened file readable (e.g. sys.stdout)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084916/how-does-one-make-an-already-opened-file-readable-e-g-sys-stdout/61087617#61087617)